# How to select different values from the same joined table but on different foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, view

I have a table `Users` which is linked to multiple times like below :

[image]

So when I request `Name` for a `Request` from Users I get one of the names, I would like both, its the first time I've faced this situation and I don't know how to do it from SQL.

Query could be like :

```
SELECT Name as Originator, Name as Requestee FROM View ... JOIN ... WHERE Id = 123
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple, you need two users, you join the `Users` table twice, like:

```
SELECT ou.Name as Originator, ru.Name as Requestee 
FROM Requests r
  INNER JOIN Users ou ON r.Originator_Id = ou.Id
  INNER JOIN Users ru ON r.Requestee_Id = ru.Id
WHERE r.Id = 123
```

Comment: And use `LEFT` joins if any of the two Ids is nullable.